# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (50,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on my mid-term project. The goal is find and print out the equations of the tangent lines of f(x)=x^2 - 26x -169 through point A(0;-8788). Then plot f(x), tangent lines, point A on the same figure.
But it went wrong since i started to plot.
Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
x,x0,y0,k= sp.symbols('x x0 y0 k')
fx = x ** 2 - 2 * 13 * x - 13 ** 2
df = sp.diff(fx, x)    
delta = df*(x-x0)+(y0)          
yy = delta.subs([(x0,0),(y0,-4*(13**3))])
y_tangentLine = delta.subs([(x0,0),(y0,-4*(13**3)),(df,k)])
y = yy - fx                  
sol = sp.solve( y, x)
for i in range(len(sol)):
    x1 = (sol[0])               
    x2 = (sol[1])
k1 = df.subs(x,x1)              
k2 = df.subs(x,x2)             
y1 = y_tangentLine.subs(k,k1)
y2 = y_tangentLine.subs(k,k2)
print("Equation of the tangent line 1 to the curve f(x) :", y1)
print("Equation of the tangent line 1 to the curve f(x) :", y2)
x = np.linspace(-500, 500,50)
fx = x ** 2 - 2 * 13 * x - 13 ** 2
y1 = x*(-26*math.sqrt(51) - 26) - 8788
plt.plot(x,fx)
plt.plot(0, -4*13**3,'rD')
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.title("Question 1c")
plt.show()
```

Here is the full trace:

```
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\demo.py 
Equation of the tangent line 1 to the curve f(x) : x*(-26*sqrt(51) - 26) - 8788
Equation of the tangent line 1 to the curve f(x) : x*(-26 + 26*sqrt(51)) - 8788
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\demo.py", line 92, in <module>
    c()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\demo.py", line 87, in c
    plt.plot(x1,y1)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3575, in plot
    return gca().plot(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1721, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(self, *args, data=data, **kwargs)]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 303, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 499, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (50,)
```

I'm very new to Python and i spent a whole week on this thing. This is the last step to finish my project but i'm stuck.
I read many posts but it didn't work.
Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: Take a look at the lines `for i in range(len(sol)): x1 = (sol[0]); x2 = (sol[1])`.

Comment: Is there something wrong with it? I still dont realize it. Could you show me?

Comment: The first thing to notice is that you're not using the value of `i` anywhere, so you're just creating `x1` and `x2` inside the loop, *always* accessing the first and second values  
 of `sol`, and without storing the variables inside a list for further access (thus discarding them on every iteration).